# How to get number of days between two date ranges

Tags: laravel, date, laravel-5

I have two date fields Start and End

```
         <input type="date" name="start>
         <input type="date" name="end>
```

Now i want to get number of days between the selected range and all the dates which comes in this range.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Comment: There is so many questions regarding this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Carbon's `diffInDays()` method:

```
Carbon::parse(request('start'))->diffInDays(Carbon::parse(request('end')));
```

To list all the dates between these two dates:

```
$period = new DatePeriod(Carbon::parse(request('start')), CarbonInterval::day(), Carbon::parse(request('end')));
foreach ($period as $date) {
    echo $date;
}
```

Comment: great it shows the number of days and how i get the dates which comes in this range ?

Comment: This does not include the start date. I want to get the count in days from start to end like date 16-25 I think return should be 10 days. But returning 9 days. should include 16 and 25 dates also.
How I will do that?

Answer (score 1):

Use `CarbonPeriod` to get day beetween two date

```
$period = \Carbon\CarbonPeriod::create(request('start'), request('end'));
foreach ($period as $key => $date) {
   dump($date->format('Y-m-d'));
}
```

With carbon period you can get both start and end date.